# What is the asymptotic behavior of the Levy distribution $P (x)$ when the independent variable $x$ approaches $0$

Tags: fourier-transform

What is the asymptotic behavior of the Levy distribution
$$P(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty \exp(-\gamma q^\alpha)\cos qx\,dq$$
when the independent variable $x$ approaches $0$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: for small $x$ you have $\log P(x)\propto -1/x$.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer, are there some references please.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lévy_distribution

Comment: Sorry, since I didn't state the definition of levy step-by-step before, the answer you gave doesn't match my question. I modified the question, can you help answer it again.

Comment: I converted your image to an equation; why is this function called Levy distribution?

Comment: because it is from website: https://galileo-unbound.blog/2023/02/08/paul-levys-black-swan-the-physics-of-outliers/.Excuse me, my illustration has small problem, now the levy distribution should be said as Lévy symmetric stable distribution.

Answer (score 1):

$$P_{\alpha,\gamma}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty \exp(-\gamma q^\alpha)\cos qx\,dq$$
$$=\frac{1}{\pi}\gamma^{-1/\alpha} \Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)-\frac{1}{2\pi\alpha}x^2 \gamma^{-3/\alpha} \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)+{\cal O}(x^4).$$

---

To check, I take $\alpha=1$ or $\alpha=2$, when
$$P_{1,\gamma}(x)=\frac{\gamma}{\gamma^2+x^2}=\frac{1}{\gamma}-\frac{x^2}{\gamma^3}+{\cal O}(x^4),$$
$$P_{2,\gamma}(x)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 \gamma}}}{2 \sqrt{\gamma}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2 \sqrt{\gamma}}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } x^2}{8 \gamma^{3/2}}+{\cal O}(x^4),$$
in agreement with the expansion above.

Comment: Thank you! Did you calculate this integral with Taylor expansion?

Comment: yes, assuming $\gamma>0$ and $\alpha>0$ so that the integral converges

Comment: Thank you, because q is taking from 0 to infinite ,does not Taylor expansion work? what is more ,if \alpha is less than 0 , the result of integral?

Comment: for $\alpha\leq 0$ the integral is divergent

Comment: Taylor expansion works because the integral is dominated by the small-$q$ region; as a check, I added the cases $\alpha=1$ and $\alpha=2$, which can be evaluated in closed form.